# Android activity from left to right in front

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to know what is the type of Android Activity implemented in the image where you can put for example configurations and hide it with a swipe gesture

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Because from photo it looks like you are talking about NavigationDrawer
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `Navigation Drawer` ,The `Navigation Drawer` is a panel that transitions in from the left edge of the screen and displays the app’s main navigation options.

for more information you can visit developer  [Link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

[image]

[image]

Following are the GitHub links where you can find `Navigation Drawer` source code

[Navigation Drawer Source Code Link 1](https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation)

[Navigation Drawer Source Code Link2](https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu)

[Navigation Drawer Source Code Link 3](https://github.com/Gregadeaux/android-fly-in-app-navigation)

[Navigation Drawer Source Code Link 4](https://github.com/leonardosalles/shipp-sliding-menu)

[More Collection](http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/07/developing-facebook-sidebar-menu-in.html)

Comment: Please add the actual answer and some description to the links, once a link dies the answer is useless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried on API level 8 and 18. And it worked. But it didnt worked on API level 10. Do you have any comment for this issue. Thanx.

Answer (score 3):

It is [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) a panel that transitions in from the left edge of the screen and displays the app’s main navigation options.

[image]

You can find how to [Create a Navigation Drawer here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The drawer view (the ListView) must specify its horizontal gravity with the android:layout_gravity attribute. To support right-to-left (RTL) languages, specify the value with "start" instead of "left" (so the drawer appears on the right when the layout is RTL).

Comment: Does anyone know how to implement the thumbnail icons next to the text in the drawer? I've already implemented the NavigtionDrawer but I can't find a way to add images to each list item. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That is referred to either as a sliding menu or a [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Google released their own implementation for this last week: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

The most popular implementation prior to that was probably [this `SlidingMenu` component](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).